# Execute a JAR file in a specific JRE

Tags: java, linux

I have been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757851/run-a-jar-file-using-a-specific-jre) and although it shows how you can execute a `jar` in Windows, it does not show how this can be done in Linux (preferably [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)). How can I execute the `.jar` file I made in Linux?

Here is what I have on the command line:

```
[support@turndownForWhat project]$ ls
DICOMFLOW.jar  jre1.7.0_60
```

UPDATE: I have tried this:

```
[support@turndownForWhat project]$ sudo jre1.7.0_60/bin/java -jar DICOMFLOW.jar
[sudo] password for support:
sudo: jre1.7.0_60/bin/java: command not found
```

I ran:

```
[root@turndownForWhat project]# ls -l jre1.7.0_60/bin/java
-rw-rw-r-- 1 support support 5718 Apr 17  2014 jre1.7.0_60/bin/java
```

Comment: does `jre1.7.0_60` contain a directory `bin`? Does the `bin` directory contain a file `java`?

Comment: What does this command print? `ls -l jre1.7.0_60/bin/java`

Comment: java does have bin and the java file, I made sure of it

Comment: `java` is not executable.  This would suggest a problem when you copying or uncompressed the directory.

Comment: @whiskeyspider, that would explain it. You are correct..Mind putting that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your reported output, the `java` command is not executable.  This is likely an issue with the copying or uncompressing of the JRE directory.

Comment: I unzipped jre-6u41-linux-i586.bin with "unzip jre-6u41-linux-i586.bin" successfully. but I still get the error. so how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty much the same, just without the `.exe`:

```
<path_to_jre>/bin/java -jar Executable.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as executing in Windows:

```
<path to bin folder for the specific JRE>/java  -jar Executable.jar
```

Make sure you can `ls` to the directory with the same path.

Comment: make sure the directory exists and you can ls to it

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter whether the JAR file was created on Linux or Windows or is to be executed on Mac. That's why it is called *portable*.

Just use the `java -jar` command with the specific [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) you want to use (add the path of the bin folder or create an alias ans use something like `java7 -jar ...`).

Comment: Hold a tick, ill try that out.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15\bin\java" -jar jenkins.war

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).