# Java: Jar is not giving output on command prompt but working fine in eclipse

Tags: java

```
public class WriteToFile {
    private static final String ELEMENT_CONFIGURATION_LIST_MARSHALLER = "elementConfigurationListMarshaller";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (String input : args) {
                System.out.println(getHashFromXml(input));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    private static String getHashFromXml(String value) throws IOException {
        SHA256Hashing calculatedHash = new SHA256Hashing();
        BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(value));
        String line;
        boolean xmlHashRemoved = false;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!xmlHashRemoved) {
                int tagIndex = line
                        .indexOf('<' + ELEMENT_CONFIGURATION_LIST_MARSHALLER);
                if (tagIndex >= 0) {
                    line = line.replaceFirst('<'
                            + ELEMENT_CONFIGURATION_LIST_MARSHALLER + " .*"
                            + '>',
                            '<' + ELEMENT_CONFIGURATION_LIST_MARSHALLER + '>');
                    xmlHashRemoved = true;
                }
            }
            calculatedHash.update(line + '\n');
        }
        return calculatedHash.toString();
    }
}
```

> 1) Eclipse: Output "583427bc82815de1ce1d22bc54a4c879f98f00cb3c91b3be8ede85cd40831b98"
>   2) java -cp FileReader.jar WriteToFile.jar  C:/WC/10.3/66830/Export_admin_202005260846.xml: 
>    "8e9bdbf9aec3c9b4be3879c3b352eacc31960c9f718e391142ab819644a525a9"

Code and input are the same but the output is different.

Comment: what is the name of  jar ??

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking why the hashes are different?

Comment: you command is wrong even though the jar is not executing so that's the reason you are not getting any output.

Comment: yes, hashes are different, code and input are same.

Comment: tell me the jar name which contains this class and dependent jars your passing along .

Answer (score 1):

Please check the JRE version used in Eclipse and run with same version of JRE in command
please follow this to run jar  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757851/run-a-jar-file-using-a-specific-jre/51615970)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you manage your dependency accordingly
`java -cp /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hadoop/conf/log4j.properties:./conf:x.jar:myjar.jar com.mycom.WriteToFile`

Comment: This may have been intended for a different question; it does not appear to be related.

Comment: ```myjar ``` is my main jar which will contain the main class and ``` x.jar``` is my other dependent jar ```:``` you can use this separator for more dependency.

Comment: Required your explanation, please @DaveNewton